# Superagent and create-react-app error, Module not found

Tags: reactjs, superagent

I am trying to use `superagent` with the `create-react-app` bootstrapper. I get the error:

Error in ./src/ToDoApp.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `node_modules\superagent\lib\client.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk - File does not exist.

I am importing the modules:

```
import request from 'superagent';
import noCache from 'superagent-no-cache';
```

I am using my `request.get` in `ComponentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount(){
      request.get(this.apiUrl)
      .use(noCache)
      .end(function _requestCallback() {
          // this.setState({data:res.data});
          console.log('gotit');
      });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

An idea: install a newer version of both modules and try again

Comment: Please explain basic details on how to solve the problem instead of pointing it the different question/source

Comment: @Harwee, I'm sorry, this is my first answer ever. Thanks.